# My Cucumber script doesn't seem to be picking up my Ruby script

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I am very new to Cucumber and Ruby, so please forgive me if what I'm missing seems simple. I'm able to run my Cucumber script, and it gives me the following result:

```
Feature: guru99 Demopage Login

  In order to Login in Demopage we have to enter login details

  Scenario: Register On Guru99 Demopage without email # test.feature:5
    Given I am on the Guru homepage                   # test.feature:7
    When enter blank details for Register             # test.feature:9
    Then error email shown                            # test.feature:11

1 scenario (1 undefined)
3 steps (3 undefined)
0m0.040s

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Given(/^I am on the Guru homepage$/) do
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end

When(/^enter blank details for Register$/) do
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end

Then(/^error email shown$/) do
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end
```

This is expected. However, when I add my .rb file which contains:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'colorize'

browser = Watir::Browser.new

Given(/^I am on the Guru homepage$/) do
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end

When(/^enter blank details for Register$/) do
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end

Then(/^error email shown$/) do
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end
```

Running the Cucumber script returns the exact same result as it did before. I have everything in a folder called "features" and the .rb file is in a subfolder of that called step_definitions. What am I doing wrong? I can't seem to find an answer online, so any help at all will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what are you naming each file?

Comment: test.feature and test_steps.rb @JeffPrice

Comment: and what does your directory structure look like? Also, can you run cucumber with -verbose option which will show everything that is being loaded.

Comment: everything is in a folder called "features" with a test.feature in it, and a subfolder called "step-definitions" containing test_steps.rb

Comment: @JeffPrice is this what you're looking for?

http://pastebin.com/6GY6EndJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your feature files and step definitions are in `features` folder, try to run cucumber with `--require features` option.

Comment: So that fixed it, but why? How can I fix this so I don't have to run it with that option every time? Is there a way to?

Comment: Yes, place a cucumber.yml file in the config directory off of your project root. Please see: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/cucumber.yml

Comment: It fixed the issue because you told cucumber to require all the files in the features directory and all of it's sub directories.